# Weglot Translation Not able to translate the checkout payment section

Tags: wordpress, translation, multilingual

I am using Weglot Translation Plugins in WordPress. Everything working fine except checkout payment section not updating that's why the translation not working for that particular section
Check below the screenshot

[image]

https://prnt.sc/1zs8ptj

Answer (score 1):

I'm Edson from weglot developper team.

Regarding your problem there are 2 things:
1- first of all, you should check from the dahboard if your translation is present. If not, one of the first ways is to see if you haven't gone over your word limit.

2- The error you are reporting seems "normal" because the Visual Editor must be used for "static" pages. In your case, you seem to be using the tool to translate an order page containing Ajax calls which notably causes CORS header issues.

I hope this will help you and do not hesitate if you have any questions to contact our support team

Best

Comment: Hi, @Edson Galina Fortes thank you to reach to me. I am well aware of the word limit I have approx 400 words pending in the limit and for 2nd I notice CC form is loading from the Iframe from Stripe that's why it's not translating but I also found a solution for this in Weglot Translate Iframe  https://developers.weglot.com/javascript/translate-iframe  but its not clear to me how it will work